# How to check for the length of object's property name

Tags: javascript

I have an object like below:

```
var car =
{ 
    "bmw":
    {
       "price": $100000  
    }  
};
```

I am checking if property-price exists in the object-car:

```
    var checkPropertyExistsInObject = function(obj, property) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
                return false;
            }
            obj = obj[args[i]];
        }
        return true;
    }

if(checkPropertyExistsInObject(car,'bmw','price')){
             return true ;
else 
               return false;
```

I am able to check if property-price exists in object-car but I want to check for the property-price 's length(not price's value length) too. I am not able to figure the condition how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: What do you mean? If you know the property path you also know the length of the property path... `['bmw', 'price'].join('').length`

Comment: Wtf is that dollar sign doing before that int? While I wouldn't be surprised if it was new ES6 feature I think it's not the case.

Comment: So you want to check the length of a key you know upfront? Like `"price".length`?

Comment: @pawel yes I would like to that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys` to iterate over the keys of an object, like this:

```
var o = {bmw: {price: 1000}},
keys = Object.keys(o),
length = -1
for (var i = 0; i< keys.length; i++){
  var key = keys[i];
  if (key == 'bmw'){
    length = key.length; // access the length here;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: But if you want to check the length of the string `"bmw"` you can just check `"bmw".length`, right? A key equal to a supplied string can not have any other length than the string.

Comment: @pawel that's right, the above code is silly. It's just an illustration on how to use the `Object.keys` method

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys provide all keys of that Object as an array . Check length of the key .

```
if(checkPropertyExistsInObject(car,'bmw','price')){
 // Length of the key
 return Object.keys(car['bmw'])[0].length

} else{
 return false;
}
```